# overflow by clicking the maximize button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a website like http://www.joshuasortino.com/. By clicking this maximize button, the sidebar, nav sections are automatically overflow. How is it possible? Any css trick or any js need? Please let me know your comments. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's called Responsive web design.

It's using the @media queries trick to detect the user browser width and change the styling in response to the width.

read here for more information :
[Responsive Design from Official Google Web Master Central](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/04/responsive-design-harnessing-power-of.html)

For another sample, you can see it from here :
[Media Queries](http://mediaqueri.es/)

Answer (score 0):

I'ts a combination of `JavaScript` and `CSS`

[jQuery Plugin for test resize](http://fittextjs.com/)

Conditional CSS:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles/home.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles/home-devices.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 641px)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles/home-iphone.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"/>
```

Comment: I have included this Conditional CSS in my test file. But it is not work. Any js need?